# limit of $\cos(a_n)$, where $\{a_n\} \to 0$

Tags: analysis, limits, trigonometry

Let $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \to 0$$

How would you prove the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(a_n) = 1$$

I'm trying to do this using the definition of a cauchy sequence:

$$ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \left| a_n - a_m \right| \leq \epsilon \, \forall n, m \geq N$$

And thus I'd like to conclude that $\{cos(a_n)\}$ is also cauchy, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: It depends on how you define the cosine function. Are you defining it as the first coordinate function restricted to the circle, are you defining it as a power series ... ?

Answer (score 1):

would you mind if I just say cos x is a continous function with out my answer has any $\epsilon$ or $\delta$?

Answer (score 1):

Using

$$\cos(A)-\cos(B) =2  \sin(\frac{A+B}{2}) \sin(\frac{B-A}{2})    $$

you get

$$\left| \cos(a_m)-\cos(a_n) \right|=2 \left| \sin(\frac{a_n+a_{m}}{2}) \sin(\frac{a_m-a_n}{2})   \right| $$

Now use
$$\left| \sin(\frac{a_n+a_{m}}{2})   \right| \leq 1$$
$$\left|  \sin(\frac{a_m-a_n}{2})   \right| \leq \left| \frac{a_m-a_n}{2}\right|$$

**Comment:** You don't need to show that $\cos(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

You have

$$\left| \cos(a_n)-1 \right|=\left| \cos(a_n)-\cos(0) \right|=2 \left| \sin(\frac{a_n}{2}) \sin(\frac{-a_n}{2}) \right| \leq 2\left| \frac{a_n}{2} \right|  $$